# Comparing computer vision libraries in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, scikit-learn

I want to decide about a Python computer vision library. I had used OpenCV in C++, and like it very much. However this time I need to develop my algorithm in Python. My short list has three libraries:
1- *OpenCV* (Python wrapper)
2- *PIL* (Python Image Processing Library)
3- *scikit-image*

**Would you please help me to compare these libraries?**

I use *numpy, scipy, scikit-learn* in the rest of my code. The performance and ease of use is an important factor, also, portability is an important factor for me.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have worked mainly with OpenCV and also with scikit-image. I would say that while OpenCV is more focus on computer vision (classification, feature detection and extraction,...). However lately scikit-image is improving rapidly. 
I faced that some algorithms perform faster under OpenCV, however in most cases I find much more easier working with scikit-image, OpenCV documentations is quite cryptic.
As long as OpenCV 2.x bindings works with numpy as well as scikit-image I would take into account using both libraries, trying to take the better of each of them. At least is what I have done in my last project.